# LINQ to Entities joining on instance rather than id generates nasty SQL

Tags: join, linq-to-entities

Can anyone explain why join by entity rather than id generates some really ugly sql when actually conceptually its doing what you'd think was the same thing? e.g.

By id

```
from companyDirector in CompanyDirectors
join contactAddress in ContactAddresses
  on companyDirector.ContactAddress.Id equals contactAddress.Id
select new {companyDirector, contactAddress}
```

Generates

```
FROM  [COMPANY] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] = [Extent2].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID]
```

By instance

```
from companyDirector in CompanyDirectors
join contactAddress in ContactAddresses
  on companyDirector.ContactAddress equals contactAddress
select new {companyDirector, contactAddress}
```

generates

```
FROM  [COMPANY] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [ADDRESS] AS [Extent2] ON  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM    ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent3].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] AS [CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID]
        FROM [ADDRESS] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] = [Extent3].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        [Extent4].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] AS [CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID]
        FROM [ADDRESS] AS [Extent4]
        WHERE [Extent1].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] = [Extent4].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] ) AS [Project2] ON 1 = 1
    WHERE [Project1].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID] = [Extent2].[CONTACT_ADDRESS_ID]
)
```

That looks pretty inefficient to me, forcing you into the id route. Why is it doing the left join twice, never mind once??

Comment: Even this question is very good we can hardly answer it here. That's the question for ADO.NET team.

Comment: if the ADO.NET team are not subscribed to these keywords they need to be in someone's crosshair :)

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't write either one. I'd write `from companyDirector in CompanyDirectors from contactAddress in companyDirector.ContactAddresses select new {companyDirector, contactAddress}` which should work correctly and doesn't require knowledge of the DB schema to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, for me EF still lacks the maturity and features required to perform in the big wide world. So I dropped it in favour of NHibernate which generates simply beautiful and optimised SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what is in the minds or the code of the ADO.NET team.  That said, I see two possible issues:

1. Possibly, the `Id` field in the underlying table in `ContractAddresses`, or possibly just in the entity model, could not be defined as a primary key.  I somewhat doubt this is the problem, but it's worth double-checking.
2. The `equals` keyword may not have a good way actually to compare equality between the two objects in the join.  In a quick web search, I did not find *exactly* what the `equals` uses for comparison, but [this MSDN how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx) leads me to believe that the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods are involved (even if composite keys are not involved).  If you are just using the default `object.Equals` inherited method, the Linq provider has to figure out the reference equality somehow, which I imagine could lead to some strange results.

I do like the solution by @Craig Stuntz in his comment, though.  Also, you might want to get an execution plan for the longer query to see if it's really as bad as it looks; the query optimizer might do a better job than the code would indicate.